# In a key value pair, can a key be another k-v pair?

Tags: json, mongodb, key-value

I know the following JSON objects are valid KV pairs:

```
{a:1,b:45,h:98}

{a:1,b:45,h:[a:1,b:45,h:98]}
```

-- Value of Key h is another array of KVP

```
{a:1,b:45,h:[98,97,65,43]}
```

But is this valid:

```
{a:1,b:45,{a:1,b:45,h:98}:98}
```

context is MongoDB's JSON objects

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve in MongoDB context?

Answer (score 0):

No.  MongoDB uses JSON syntax and stores objects as JSON (well, technically BSON).  [json.org](http://www.json.org/) says very explicitly that the syntax for objects -- the things between `{}`, is `string : value`.  In the same document, it goes on to say:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes

This would preclude you from using an object literal as a key.

I think that if you think about it enough you would realize that it doesn't make sense to use anything other than a string as a key anyway.